# Saving related data using EF Core in ASP.NET Core application

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am getting the customer, billing and shipping details using a viewmodel into my controller and trying to save the data. As the customerid is not being set initially, I am getting an error related to foreign key. I am unable to understand what went wrong in this.

```
 public class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            BillingAddress = new BillingAddress();
        }
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public BillingAddress BillingAddress { get; set; }
    }

public class BillingAddress
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}      

public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public CustomerController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SaveCustomerDetails(CustomerViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(viewModel);

        Customer customer = new Customer
        {
            FirstName = viewModel.FirstName,
            LastName = viewModel.LastName
        };
        _unitOfWork.Customers.Add(customer);            
        BillingAddress billingAddress = new BillingAddress
        {
            Address1 = viewModel.BillingAddress.Address1,
            City = viewModel.BillingAddress.City,
            State = viewModel.BillingAddress.State
            CustomerId = customer.Id
        };
        _unitOfWork.BillingAddress.Add(billingAddress);
        _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is _unitOfWork your DbContext? You have a confusing model. A Customer can have multiple billing address based on CustomerId in BA class. But you have a single BillingAddress property in Customer. If Customer has multiple BA then should be a list property.

Comment: How did you implements your IUnitOfWork?And what is your error message?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to build up your object graph prior to calling save changes - EF will take care of it.

This is much better than calling save changes to get the ID And then saving the address.  This way will be a single DB hit and be a single transaction (i.e. all succeed or all fail) rather than intermediate saves that may leave the DB in an unexpected state if one of them fails:

```
public IActionResult SaveCustomerDetails(CustomerViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(viewModel);

    Customer customer = new Customer
    {
        FirstName = viewModel.FirstName,
        LastName = viewModel.LastName,
        BillingAddress = new BillingAddress
        {
           Address1 = viewModel.BillingAddress.Address1,
           City = viewModel.BillingAddress.City,
           State = viewModel.BillingAddress.State
        }
    };

    _unitOfWork.Customers.Add(customer);            

    _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();

    return View("Index");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked well. I just have a query, is this a change related to newer version of EF?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working demo like below:

Model:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        BillingAddress = new BillingAddress();
    }
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public BillingAddress BillingAddress { get; set; }
}

public class BillingAddress
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public BillingAddress BillingAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class CustomersController : Controller
{
    private readonly MvcProjContext _context;

    public CustomersController(MvcProjContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(CustomerViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(viewModel);

        Customer customer = new Customer
        {
            FirstName = viewModel.FirstName,
            LastName = viewModel.LastName
        };
        _context.Customer.Add(customer);
        _context.SaveChanges();//add this line

        //find the added customer id
        var CustomerId = _context.Customer
                            .Where(c => c.FirstName == viewModel.FirstName && c.LastName == viewModel.LastName)
                            .Select(c => c.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        BillingAddress billingAddress = new BillingAddress
        {
            Address1 = viewModel.BillingAddress.Address1,
            City = viewModel.BillingAddress.City,
            CustomerId = CustomerId
        };
        _context.BillingAddress.Add(billingAddress);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
}
```